# What is the best practice to store resources (images, json files, other assets) in your flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to restructure my project and I currently have a folder `res/` with `images/` for images, `raw/` for json files I parse etc, but I wonder if there is a best practice to do things another way.

Comment: Flutter uses the term "assets".  Are you familiar with https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images?

Comment: I have read an old version of this I think. So my current structure is fine and to be in line with flutter guidelines all I have to change is the term "res" to "assets"?